# Automatically create donut polygons based on distance from boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, buffer, donut-polygons

I have a file with polygons representing risk of townships however the risk decreases inside each polygon so I'm wanting to create rings from each polygon for example from the boundary to 500m then another ring from 500m from the boundary to 750m from the boundary then another ring from 750m from the boundary to 1000m from the boundary and so on
I can do this manually by creating donut polygons but I was hoping for a more automated solution.

Comment: Look at multiple ring buffer http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001p000000, there's an option for overlapping and non-overlapping rings.

Comment: Convert your polygons to polylines and calculate euclidian distance to it. Erase raster outside polygons and reclassify result using 500 increment. Vector solution is more hectic

Answer (score 1):

The [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) tool would seem to be the place to start your investigations:

> Creates multiple buffers at specified distances around the input
>   features. These buffers can optionally be merged and dissolved using
>   the buffer distance values to create non-overlapping buffers.

Comment: I always thought it works on points only and does not on polygons especially with negative buffers

Comment: @FelixIP The Illustration at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm shows a polygon being multiple buffered.  I don't recall trying that tool recently but I think the asker should.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple ring buffer. That is what I want to do but in reverse. I'm not sure how this would work though?

Comment: @AJ1984 I think you should edit your question to describe what you mean by "in reverse" of what the Multiple Ring Buffer tool does.